# AWS Beanstalk Tomcat and Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I try to set up a Tomcat using Beanstalk.

Here's my Terraform code:

(bucket is created beforehand)

```
# Upload the JAR to bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "myjar" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id}"
  key    = "src/java-tomcat-v3.zip"
  source = "${path.module}/src/java-tomcat-v3.zip"
  etag   = "${md5(file("${path.module}/src/java-tomcat-v3.zip"))}"
}

# Define app
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "tftestapp" {
  name        = "tf-test-name"
  description = "tf-test-desc"
}

# Define beanstalk jar version
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "myjarversion" {
  name         = "tf-test-version-label"
  application  = "tf-test-name"
  description  = "My description"
  bucket       = "${aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id}"
  key          = "${aws_s3_bucket_object.myjar.id}"
  force_delete = true
}

# Deploy env
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "tftestenv" {
  name                = "tf-test-name"
  application         = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.tftestapp.name}"
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v3.0.0 running Tomcat 7 Java 7"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MinSize"
    value     = "1"
  }
  ...
}
```

And I end up with a very strange error, saying it can't find the file on the bucket.

> InvalidParameterCombination: Unable to download from S3 location
>   (Bucket: mybucket  Key: src/java-tomcat-v3.zip). Reason: Not Found

Nevertheless, connecting to the web console and accessing my bucket, I can see the zip file is right there...

I don't get it, any help please?

PS: I tried with and without the `src/`

Cheers

Comment: Is this error coming from Terraform or from Beanstalk?

Comment: This error is coming from Terraform. It says it can't apply, and gives this error...

Answer (score 0):

I was recently having this same error on Terraform 0.13.

Differences between 0.13 and older versions:
The documentation appears to be out of date.  For instance, under **aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version** it shows

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "default" {
  bucket = "tftest.applicationversion.bucket"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "default" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.default.id
  key    = "beanstalk/go-v1.zip"
  source = "go-v1.zip"
}
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "default" {
  name        = "tf-test-name"
  description = "tf-test-desc"
}
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "default" {
  name        = "tf-test-version-label"
  application = "tf-test-name"
  description = "application version created by terraform"
  bucket      = aws_s3_bucket.default.id
  key         = aws_s3_bucket_object.default.id
}
```

If you attempt to use this, terraform fails with the bucket object because the "source" argument is no longer available within aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version.
After removing the "source" property, it moved to the *next* issue, which was `Error: InvalidParameterCombination: Unable to download from S3 location (Bucket: mybucket  Key: mybucket/myfile.txt). Reason: Not Found`

This error comes from the terraform:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "mybucket"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "default" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  key    = "myfile.txt"
}
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "default" {
  name        = "tf-test-name"
  description = "tf-test-desc"
}
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "default" {
  name        = "tf-test-version-label"
  application = "tf-test-name"
  description = "application version created by terraform"
  bucket      = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  key         = aws_s3_bucket_object.default.id
}
```

What Terraform ends up doing here is it prepends the bucket to the key.  When you run `terraform plan` you see that bucket = "mybucket" and key = "mybucket/myfile.txt".  The problem with this is that Terraform looks in the bucket for the file "mybucket/myfile.txt" when it should ONLY be looking for "myfile.txt"

## Solution

What I did was REMOVE the bucket and bucket object resources from the script and place the names in variables, as follows:

```
variable "sourceCodeS3BucketName" {
   type = string
   description = "The bucket that contains the engine code."
   default = "mybucket"
}
variable "sourceCodeFilename" {
   type = string
   description = "The code file name."
   default = "myfile.txt"
}
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "myApp" {
  name        = "my-beanstalk-app"
  description = "My application"
}
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "v1_0_0" {
  name        = "my-application-v1_0_0"
  application = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.myApp.name
  description = "Application v1.0.0"
  bucket      = var.sourceCodeS3BucketName
  key         = var.sourceCodeFilename
}
```

By directly using the name of the file and the bucket, Terraform does not prepend the bucket name to the key, and it can find the file just fine.